# $\int \frac{1}{y-1} dy = \ln |y - 1|$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I read the following in a book on differential equations

$$\int \frac{1}{y-1} dy = \log |y - 1|$$

If I put $\int \frac{1}{y-1} dy$ into Wolfram Alpha it gives $\log (y - 1)$, i.e. the argument of the function is not an absolute value unlike the first equation. So which is correct and why am I seeing conflicting results for the same integral?

Comment: the first one is correct

Comment: The first is correct but I think that Wolfram Alpha assumes that $y>1$.

Comment: Did you try to check each of them *yourself*?

Comment: 1)it should be $\log|y-1| +C$, 2) real log function is defined only for positive arguments

Comment: There is a good explanation of this in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntxVfAwplwY

Comment: Neither is really completely right. If we want all the functions with largest (real domain) whose derivative is $y-1$, it should be $F(y)=\ln(y-1)+C$ when $y\gt 1$; $F(y)=\ln(1-y)+D$ when $y\lt 1$. Here $C$ and $D$ are arbitrary constants, not necessarily equal.

Answer (score 3):

That happens because $\log (y - 1)$ only exists in $(1, +\infty)$, hence its derivative would be $1/(y - 1)$, but with considering only values of $y$ that are greater than $1$.

This is of course different from what you are trying to integrate, because that $1/(y - 1)$ inside the integral is a function that is defined everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$ (with the sole exception of $1$). Then its indefinite integral is $\log |y - 1|$ because not only its derivative is $1/(y - 1)$, but its domain is also exactly $\mathbb{R} - \{1\}$, that is the same of the function you're trying to integrate.

This happens because functions with different domains are different functions even if their written expression is the same, so $1/(y - 1)$ may yield different results when integrating, according to what its domain is.